# Os cabeçalhos HTTP são case sensitive ou case insensitive?

Tags: http, http-headers, sensibilidade-de-caixa

- Dois cabeçalhos com o mesmo nome porém um em maiúscula e outro em minúscula, por padrão, são considerados o mesmo?
- O que o HTTP faz, uni eles, ignora algum ou envia ambos?
- Uma aplicação que espera, por exemplo, um cabeçalho `Authorization`, mas recebe um cabeçalho `authorization` deve processar usando ele ou retornar um erro?
- Há um padrão de nomenclatura definido por alguma RFC?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Eles são *case-insensitive*. Isso é definido na [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230), mais especificamente na seção [**3.2 *Header Fields***](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2).

Esta é uma das RFC's atuais que especificam o padrão HTTP 1.1. Este conjunto de RFC's tornam obsoleta a [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) que foi usada para base dessa resposta anteriormente (obrigado, [@Anderson Carlos Woss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/anderson-carlos-woss)) — felizmente, não houveram mudanças significativas na parte que vimos.

Veja o trecho que fala sobre (ênfase minha):

> *[...] Each header field consists of a **case-insensitive** field name followed by a colon (":"), optional leading whitespace, the field value, and optional trailing whitespace*.

Então, tentando responder suas perguntas:

> **Dois cabeçalhos com o mesmo nome porém um em maiúscula e outro em minúscula, por padrão, são considerados o mesmo?**

Sim, eles devem ser considerados o mesmo cabeçalho, uma vez que a especificação diz que os campos são *case-insensitive*

> O que o HTTP faz, uni eles, ignora algum ou envia ambos?

**O HTTP não faz nada**. Quem faz são as aplicações que o seguem (navegadores e servidores web). E aí não tem como dar uma resposta canônica, porque realmente depende de implementação.

É importante notar que a especificação (ainda na seção 4.2) **permite** cabeçalhos duplicados em casos que o valor do cabeçalho aceite uma lista de valores separados por vírgula, mas este é o **único caso** em que isso pode ser aceito.

Veja o que diz a RFC (novamente, ênfase por mim):

> *Multiple message-header fields with the same field-name MAY be present in a message **if and only if** the entire field-value for that header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)].*

> Uma aplicação que espera, por exemplo, um cabeçalho Authorization, mas recebe um cabeçalho authorization deve processar usando ele ou retornar um erro?

Acho que já está implícito que deve processá-lo. Pelo menos é o que diz a especificação. Ninguém pode te obrigar a implementar isso, então se você quiser construir uma aplicação que processe apenas cabeçalhos que estejam em *CamelCasing*, você pode fazê-lo. Não vai estar dentro das especificações do HTTP, mas se você consegue viver com isso, tudo bem =)

> Há um padrão de nomenclatura definido por alguma RFC?

Se fala sobre *casing*, a reposta é não, porque isso deve ser ignorado =D. Não tem muito o que "padronizar", concorda?

De forma geral, devem existir alguns esforços pra não deixar que tudo vire uma grande bagunça, como é o caso da [RFC 6648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6648) que fala sobre o prefixo `X-`.

Na [RFC 7231, seção 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5) é falado especificamente sobre os cabeçalhos HTTP, talvez seja uma boa dica de leitura pra você.

Comment: Só fique atento ao utilizar a RFC 2616 como base; ela se tornou obsoleta após as RFCs 7230, 7231, 7232, 7233, 7234 e 7235.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Muito obrigado. Eu cheguei a ver de relance no cabeçalho (perdão pelo trocadilho) da 2616, mas precisei me ausentar. Adaptei a resposta, felizmente não houveram mudanças significativas no que falamos aqui.

Answer (score 5):

Não. Cabeçalhos HTTP não são sensíveis a caso. Aqui na referência [HTTP/1.1](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2) no item 4.2 está dizendo isso.

> HTTP header fields, which include general-header (section 4.5), request-header (section 5.3), response-header (section 6.2), and entity-header (section 7.1) fields, follow the same generic format as that given in Section 3.1 of RFC 822 [9]. Each header field consists of a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value. Field names are **case-insensitive.**

---

> Dois cabeçalhos com o mesmo nome porém um em maiúscula e outro em minúscula, por padrão, são considerados o mesmo?

Sim, serão considerados os mesmos.

> O que o HTTP faz, uni eles, ignora algum ou envia ambos?

Utilizar cabeçalhos com o mesmo nome, mesmo sendo eles *case-sensitives*, irá causar problemas na plataforma que manipula os cabeçalhos recebidos. Isso depende de onde será usado, e não é uma boa prática fazer isso.

> Uma aplicação que espera, por exemplo, um cabeçalho Authorization, mas recebe um cabeçalho authorization deve processar usando ele ou retornar um erro?

De acordo com o RFC, deve considerar ambos a mesma coisa, seja o `Authorization`, `authorization` e `AUTHORIZATION`. Ambos não devem ser declarados ao mesmo tempo.

> Há um padrão de nomenclatura definido por alguma RFC?

Em junho de 2012, uma recomendação foi **não usar o X-** no início dos cabeçalhos. [Fonte](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6648).

> ### 3. Recommendations for Creators of New Parameters
>
> ...
>
> SHOULD NOT prefix their parameter names with "X-" or similar constructs.

---

> ### 4. Recommendations for Protocol Designers
>
> ...
>
> SHOULD NOT prohibit parameters with an "X-" prefix or similar constructs from being registered.
>
> MUST NOT stipulate that a parameter with an "X-" prefix or similar constructs needs to be understood as unstandardized.
>
> MUST NOT stipulate that a parameter without an "X-" prefix or similar constructs needs to be understood as standardized.

---

Fontes:

- https://pt.switch-case.com/51741167
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561381/custom-http-headers-naming-conventions
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258977/are-http-headers-case-sensitive
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718476/are-http-headers-content-type-c-case-sensitive/7718542

Comment: Só fique atento ao utilizar a RFC 2616 como base; ela se tornou obsoleta após as RFCs 7230, 7231, 7232, 7233, 7234 e 7235.

Comment: Obrigado pela observação, @AndersonCarlosWoss.